# Javascript remove element from select

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm using a form with two select lists with a button.

I'm trying that when I click the button, I pass the select element from one select list to another.

The problem is, instead of removing 1 element, the selected element is removed alongside the one that follows in the list.

Here is my function:

```
  function removeOptions(s1,s2) {

    if (s1.options.length == 0) {
        alert('You have already removed all list items');
        return false;
    }

    var optionToRemove = s1.options.selectedIndex;
    var optn = s1.options[optionToRemove];

    s2.options.add(optn);
    s1.remove(optionToRemove);


    alert('success');
    return true;
}
```

My button configuration:

```
  <input type=button onClick="removeOptions(selectList1,selectList2)" ; value='Autorizar'>
```

I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: It's not a `button configuration`, and please show use the full HTML code.

Comment: Sorry! Engineer answered to my question. Thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
 s2.options.add(optn);
 s1.remove(optionToRemove);
```

lines, try this:

```
 s2.appendChild(optn);
```

The `optn` element will be moved from `s1` element to `s2` element. The element (specifically `optn`) can't have 2 or more parents at the same time, so `optn` will be removed from `s1` automatically.